# Error while concatenating date and time columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with the following properties:

```
    Column   Non-Null Count   Dtype 
---  ------   --------------   ----- 
 0   Date     226611 non-null  object

 1   Time     226611 non-null  object

 2   Code     226611 non-null  object

 3   Message  226611 non-null  object
```

`Date` column has values as format : `2021-11-28 00:00:00` and `Time` column has values as format: `08:15:12.476000`. I am trying to create a `DateTime` column with the following code (basically tried  most of the available pandas' methods like to_datetime, to_timestampe, etc.):

```
df["DateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]+" "+df["Time"])
```

but I keep getting the following error: `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'`. Can someone point out what am I missing here? The expected output would be (restricting milliseconds to 2 digits only):

```
     Date                  Time               DateTime 

 0   2021-11-28 00:00:00   08:15:12.476000    2021-11-28 08:15:12.47
```

Comment: The error message seems clear enough: `df["Date"]` is a `datetime` object (not a string), but you're trying to add the string `" "` to it, which isn't supported

Comment: You need to convert `Date` to a string using `strftime`, then do the concatenation, then convert the whole thing back to a datetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try concatenating by datetime parts

```
df["DateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(str(pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]).dt.date)+" "+str(pd.to_datetime(df["Time"]).dt.time))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`pandas.Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html)

```py
df["DateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + " " + df["Time"])
```